# Filtered all commits in my local git repository, best way to update remote?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I ran a filter that converted all my files in all revisions to Unix line-endings.  I now see that git states all revisions of my local and remote have diverged.  Git status tells me to do a pull and merge.  What is the best way to replace all remote commits with my local commits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to do a force push.  The "best" way these days is to use `--force-with-lease` to make sure that no one else has updated the remote repository since you last obtained everything from it.  If it's a private (or mostly private) repository, of course, no one else *should* be updating it, and you can just use a regular force-push.

(The drawback to force-push is that, if it succeeds, it makes the other Git overwrite *its* branch-names with the new commit IDs you give it.  This loses all the old commits ... so anyone who was using and depending on them, now has to take care of this in *their* clone of that remote.  In this case, you really *do* want to lose all those old commits, so it's a question of whether anyone else is using them, and if so, whether you care about those other people.)

Comment: So what is the proper way to update the clones after this action?

Comment: Other clones will need to `git fetch` and then re-create / transplant any private commits. The details for "best way" vary depending on the goals. If there are no private commits to transplant or re-create, one can `git reset --hard` each branch to its corresponding remote-tracking branch, or even just remove the clone and re-clone (less work by the human, more work by the computer / network, often worth it since computer and network time tend to be very cheap).

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this worked great, and fast.

The only problem I'm dealing with now is my repository I filtered doubled the commits, there is a duplicate commit for every commit.  I didn't really want or need this, and I'm not even sure what the parent/child relationship looks like yet.

If anyone can help out with my filtering and avoiding the duplicate commits I would appreciate an answer to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274079/why-do-i-have-duplicate-commits-after-running-a-git-filter

Comment: The duplicates are a natural result of the copy behavior of filter-branch. The originals are still pointed-to by the saved original refs (and, if you did not use a `--tag-name-filter`, by all your tags, which is pretty painful since the mapping from original commit ID to copied commit ID is gone now that filter-branch has finished).