# Why do I have duplicate commits after running a git filter?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I ran the following command on my git repository to force all text files to use unix line endings.

```
git filter-branch --force --tree-filter 'git ls-files | xargs file | sed -n -e "/.*: .*text.*/s/\(.*\): .*/\1/p" | xargs dos2unix' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

According to the git log this resulted in a duplicate commit for every commit in the repository, author date and comment are same, hash as expected is new. Is that what I should have expected?  I thought it would replace the existing commits with different versions of the files.

Is there a better way to do the conversion that wouldn't result in all the extraneous commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git commits are immutable, so any time you want to change *anything* about a given commit, you actually have to create a new commit instead. This includes file content, author date/time, or parent commit. (Thus, if you change the content in one commit, you must create new commits for all those that follow.)

So yes, this is what you should expect, and no, there isn't a way to do the conversion that doesn't produce new commits. This is true for any commands that rewrite history, which includes `rebase` as well as `filter-branch`.

Read more about how this works in the [Git Internals - Git Objects](//git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) section in the Pro Git book.

Comment: Curious, would the filter command I ran have created commits where none were necessary (no crlf -> lf conversion occured) ?

Comment: @MarkE Presumably not, though I haven't tested this. (I know that's how `git rebase` works though.)

Comment: The filter-branch command is not as smart as `git rebase` in terms of deliberately skipping unmodified commits. Instead, it just creates the new commit *using the saved meta-data from the original commit* (including author and committer data). If the *tree* is unchanged and the *parents* are unchanged and all the rest of the data-and-metadata are unchanged, the "copy" commit is bit-for-bit identical to the original, so it has the same hash and therefore *is* the same commit, and gets re-used naturally. (Rebase intentionally does not preserve committer metadata when copying commits.)

Comment: Incidentally, this behavior is actually slightly buggy: commits with unusual or malformed UTF-8 messages can have their text re-encoded so that it is no longer bit-for-bit identical. This is probably a bug: Git is not supposed to be interpreting that data. It's a side effect of running everything from a script, though, so it's not easy to fix (as the actual bug is not necessarily in Git itself).